# How to run an iterated list as arguments of a function - googlemaps

Tags: python, excel, google-maps

I am new to programming and python so please don't hate. I am trying to build a program that takes a list of addresses in an excel sheet turns them into lists and then using the google maps api retrieves the distances and times of each address with each other. so far I can only hard code it to do it for one address. **My only problem so far is iterating through the gmaps.directions() arguments. I would love any help in how to do this**.
So in the end I would want multiple times and distances to compare them. Thanks

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
import xlrd



gmaps = GoogleMaps('gmaps api')

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('addressbook.xlsx')
ws1 = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
ws2 = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
col1 = ws1.col_values(1)
col2 = ws2.col_values(1)



dirs = gmaps.directions(col1[0] ,col2[0])
time = dirs['Directions']['Duration']['seconds']
dist = dirs['Directions']['Distance']['meters']



print time 
print dist
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to stick as close as possible to what you already have:

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
import xlrd



gmaps = GoogleMaps('gmaps api')

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('addressbook.xlsx')
ws1 = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
ws2 = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
col1 = ws1.col_values(1)
col2 = ws2.col_values(1)


for c1 in col1:
    for c2 in col2:
        dirs = gmaps.directions(c1 , c2)
        time = dirs['Directions']['Duration']['seconds']
        dist = dirs['Directions']['Distance']['meters']

        print time 
        print dist
```

(I don't know how new you are to programming in general, but regardless it looks like a tutorial would be in order)

Comment: Yes I am trying to learn python as a hobby. Thanks for your help I am jealous of your knowledge.

Comment: if I use zip then my two excel sheets have to have the same amount of addresses. is there another built in functions that would use all permutations of addresses?

Comment: @luketoboot That's even simpler. Edited in the above. There is an analogous function to zip (itertools.product), but a double for-loop is probably simpler.